# One Policy for several models

Tags: laravel

Is it possible to use the same policy for multiple models?

I have a model with 21 relationships and thus, the permissions for editing any of those models is the same - so I would be maintaining 22 policies.

Comment: Would you please edit your queation and share some code

Comment: You can use a trait to tackle redundant code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not use the same policy for several models, because when you create a policy, you have to register it in order to be effective, in laravel creating the policy need the model to be applied to, and  registering policy require the model that policy is applied to:

```
// in AuthServiceProvider Class:
 protected $policies = [
        Post::class => PostPolicy::class,
    ];
```

first argument here is model class ....

but:

you can use Gate, and try to make your code as generic as possible:

```
 Gate::define('update-entity', function ($user, $entity) {
// your code logic

        return ....;
    });
```

and in your Controller:

```
if (Gate::allows('update-entity', $current_entity)) {
    // The current user can update the post...
}
```

more details about Gates & Policies in:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use the same policy for several models. You just need to register it for the models inside your `AuthServiceProvider` class.

To get started, create a generic policy (name it accordingly):

```
php artisan make:policy GenericPolicy
```

Then you can register this policy for your various models.

```
// app\Providers\AuthServiceProvider.php

protected $policies = [
    \App\Models\FirstModel::class => \App\Policies\GenericPolicy::class,
    \App\Models\SecondModel::class => \App\Policies\GenericPolicy::class,
    // ... and so on
];
```